# Can I get a -1 exit code using C++ on mac?

Tags: c++, macos, unix, exitstatus

I was just wondering if it's possible to get a function in C++ on a Unix system to return -1 and not 255?

I have been programming some OpenCV stuff and realised stuff wasnt working as intended. The functions I was using were meant to return -1, but had been returning 255 the whole time. So I was just wondering if there is any configuration I'd be able to do to allow a return code of -1?

This is the example I am using from my textbook

```
int main( int argc, char** argv ) {
  int i = 0;
  cv::namedWindow( "Example3", cv::WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
  cv::VideoCapture cap;
  cap.open( std::string(argv[1]) );
  cv::Mat frame;
  for(;;) {
    cap >> frame;
    if( frame.empty() ) break; // Ran out of film
    cv::imshow( "Example3", frame );
    std::cout<<"waitkey:"<<cv::waitKey(33) << std::endl;
  }
  return -1;
}
```

Information on waitkey() can be found [here](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d7/dfc/group__highgui.html#ga5628525ad33f52eab17feebcfba38bd7)

Comment: I have updated my original post to include the information

Comment: This really has nothing to do with OpenCV...

Comment: @MrEricSir It had OpenCV code so I thought I'd just tag it for background information . Apologies if this has misled you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this issue is actually a bug with the OpenCV code. The bug has been addressed and pushed to the master branch of the [OpenCV github](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/pull/7935)

Answer (score 1):

POSIX [says](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/exit.html),

> The value of status may be `0`, `EXIT_SUCCESS`, `EXIT_FAILURE`, or any other value, though only the least significant 8 bits (that is, `status & 0377`) shall be available from `wait()` and `waitpid()`; the full value shall be available from `waitid()` and in the `siginfo_t` passed to a signal handler for `SIGCHLD`.

So, it's the shell program that narrows the value to 8 bits when it uses certain POSIX APIs to manage its children.

Comment: So its sounding like a big fat no? That or rather difficult :(

Comment: @Joey If you're programming with interprocess communication, then POSIX provides tools to pass a negative exit status. However, typical shells including OS X Bash do not receive it. This textbook was probably written with Windows in mind… but `-1` looks like a failure code and it's not clear why this example should always fail. Likely the author is confused, and this issue is tangential to the book topic anyhow.

Comment: TL;DR: Big fat no, but so what? Just delete the `return -1;` line and forget about it.

Comment: Oh I meant that its difficult if I wanted to use the -1 exit flag (so I could be lazy)... But yes, definitely would prefer the easier option. Ideally I wanted to be able to compile a program for both Mac and PC without the extra handiwork.